# how to create a federated model lstm for stock prediction in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow-federated

-i have column names ["Date","Open","High","Close","Volume","Group"]

-i created a additional column name "Group" to represent ClientID

```
df["Group"] = ""
client_id_colname = 'Group' # the column that represents client ID
print(df)
count= 0
group = ""
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  
  if count<=3000 and count >= 0:
    group = 'A'
    df.loc[count,'Group']= group
  elif count<=6000 and count >= 3001:
    group = 'B'
    df.loc[count,'Group']= group
  elif count<=9000 and count >= 6001:
    group = 'C'
    df.loc[count,'Group']= group
  else: 
    group = 'D'
    df.loc[count,'Group']= group
  count=count + 1

print(df)
```

-i also split the data into train_data and test_data:

```
train_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(
        client_ids=train_client_ids,
        create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
    )
test_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(
        client_ids=test_client_ids,
        create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
    )
```

-from here how can i create a lstm model to do federated learning and forecast the prediction for "Close" value?

Answer (score 1):

From here we need a few steps:

1. Define a `tff.learning.Model`. In this case it maybe easiest to use `tf.keras` to define and LSTM model and then use it in TFF with [`tff.learning.from_keras_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/from_keras_model?version=nightly).
2. Build a training process. One of the most frequently used training process is FedAvg, which is built with [`tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_averaging_process?version=nightly).
3. Finally, we need to write a training script to execute the process. [`tff.simulation.run_simulation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/run_simulation?version=nightly) may be very helpful here.

All three of these steps are documented in the tutorial [Federated Learning for Text Generation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation). With slight modifications to the `create_tff_model` to instead to use a Keras LSTM the framework is mostly already there. An example of building a Keras LSTM can be found at [Bidirectional LSTM on IMDB](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/bidirectional_lstm_imdb/).,